Python: Download X-DATA with yfinance
I am trying to import X-DAX data with yahoofinance using the code:
ticker = '3XJN'

df = yf.download(tickers=ticker, start="2024-06-01", end="2024-08-12", interval = "1d")

But unfortunately I always get the error message:
['3XJN']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')
With '^GDAX' it works without any problems.
Other forums refer to time zone problems without naming them specifically. I look forward to constructive help. Many thanks in advance.
df = yf.download(tickers=ticker, start="2024-06-101", end="2024-08-12", interval = "5d")
